# Write to directory seen when connecting to PC

Tags: android

I've got a little Android app written for a friend (nothing complex, just extracts data from his phone into a CSV) that works fine, except the output file gets written to the directory returned by `getExternalFilesDir()`, which is rather deep in the file system for an average user to get hold of.

When I plug my phone into my laptop/PC via USB, it mounts as an external drive. Is there a way for my app to write to that directory?

Thanks

Comment: That directory will be on that external drive. Or not?

Comment: If `getExternalFilesDir()` does not suit your needs then try `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Answer (score 0):

> When I plug my phone into my laptop/PC via USB, it mounts as an external drive. Is there a way for my app to write to that directory?

Yes, insofar as that is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. This is the equivalent of saying "I am going to write everything to the `C:` drive" on Windows. That was the dominant approach back in 1996, but we came to our senses and stopped cluttering up the root of a drive with files.

A middle ground option would be to put the file in one of the `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` locations, such as `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` (if your `minSdkVersion` is 8 or higher) or `DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` (if your `minSdkVersion` is 19 or higher).

Comment: Thanks - I trued the public directory (and DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, incidentally), but the file fails to write because the directory doesn't exist. Specifically, File.mkdirs() returns false. The app has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission granted (confirmed in Settings).

Comment: @user1381745: Make sure that you are [handling runtime permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it).